# Expo SDK 45 App store error - ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using the new expo SDK 45 and for some reason I'm experiencing some difficulties submitting the app to app store. It worked a year ago and they changed a few things now.

I get the following error message right after I try to submit:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "Application" 1.0.4 (1.0.4). Please correct the following
> issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> selectors in app: callWithArguments:, frameInfo,
> initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, isPassthrough,
> navigationType, onSuccess:, removeValuesForKeys:completion:,
> setNavigationDelegate:, setProcessPool:, toDouble,
> userContentController, viewManager. If method names in your source
> code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method
> names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future
> submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may
> be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so,
> they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical
> Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

The thing is, I'm not using any public API and all the packages used to work just fine (I just decided to update the application to a newer expo version but it's already on the store).

This is my small package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "tavneche",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~2.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Do you have any idea what could possibly cause this? because I've been trying to fix this for hours now. I heard it has something to do with the debugging tools or something like that but I'm using the eas build command with the production profile and still nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing today. It seems something has changed with how apps are accepted. Several people are reporting this same issue today (see the the responses this thread from today): https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127678.

Comment: Here is another issue with the same root problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523756/itms-90338-non-public-api-usage-processing-error-previously-working

Comment: Yeah I’m having the same issue

Answer (score 4):

For those who struggling with this, this was a backend issue. I just got a message from apple:

> "The issue has been resolved on the app validation backend. Please try resubmitting. Sorry for the trouble."

Comment: I can confirm, I built my app again without any changes, submitted again and got accepted.

Comment: You got that message just out of the blue? Was your app uploaded to AppstoreConnect or you were stuck with this error in Xcode during upload?